# Anyway to set form variables without outputing anything?

Tags: php, html

You know how you can make textbox like below then use $_POST['password'] to get its input?

```
<input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" placeholder="Enter Password" /><br/><br />
```

Would there be a way to insert fixed data without outputing anything. For example

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
    <div name = "username">abc</div> # Like for example here, I don't want to output "abc" just get the fixed input
    <label>Description </label><br>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" style="height: 150px;">Enter text here...</textarea><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br>
</form>
```

Comment: If you post this form then that's exactly where the data will go. It depends on the `name` attribute of the field. Are you asking about the `<input type="hidden">` type fields?

Comment: Yes I am asking for that ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) type:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="abc"/>
```